# static const int in switch statement from another class cause error C2051: case expression not constant

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static, switch-statement, syntax-error

I have one simple class like

```
class Person {
  static const int MALE; // in Person.cpp initialized = 1
  static const int FEMALE;//in Person.cpp initialized = 2
};
```

In Company class (Company.cpp file, I have company class) I have function with switch

```
 switch(x){// x is int passed as parameter to function
        case Person::MALE:
            //do something
        break;
        case Person::FEMALE:
            //do something
        break;
}
```

but when I try to build I got error  `error C2051: case expression not constant` for lines in case in switch above
What is a problem when it is a const ?

Comment: For things like this I suggest using `enum` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the declarations of static data members the following way

```
class Person {
  static const int MALE = 1;
  static const int FEMALE = 2;
};
```

The compiler must know the values of case labels during the compilation time.

Comment: Good answer. And BTW what is the difference between this class and enum type in practical sense?

Comment: @ShijingLv - this one looks more like Java. No comment on whether that's a good thing.

Comment: @ShijingLv: The enum declaration defines a new type, which could be used as the type of gender variables, such as the parameter `x` in that function.

Comment: Whould this actually make the switch statement compile? I would say no, but I am too far away from a c++ compiler to test it. `case` labels needs compile time constants, but the `const` keyword doesn't necessarily make variables constant, only readonly

Comment: @ShijingLv:  You can take the address of a `static const`, but not an `enum`.  Whether or not that makes a difference really depends on your program.

Answer (score 3):

A `const` is not a constant expression unless

- It is a `const` variable of integral type, **previously** initialized with a literal or other constant expression.

C++11 adds `constexpr`, which can be used with variables of non-integral type, but the requirement for a prior initialization still applies.

Your problem is that in Company.cpp, this variable has not been initialized.  The compiler will have to assume that the actual definition involves a runtime calculation.  For example, it is perfectly legal to write `const int Person::MALE = rand();`

Or if Person.cpp contained

```
const int Person::MALE = 1;
const int Person::FEMALE = 1;
```

then the compiler would have to reject Company.cpp because the cases are not unique.  How would that work?  What if someone edited Person.cpp after Company.cpp was already compiled?

Answer (score 1):

Values used in `case` expressions should be already known on compile-time, because they are somewhat "hardcoded" into binary code. And here they are specified only at a linkage phase. Probably the solution might be following:

```
// person.h
enum Person { MALE, FEMALE };
```

Comment: -1:  Making it an `enum` will help the compiler to pass the code, but it only skirts around the problem and isn't what OP wanted to do:  use a `static const`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++11 standard: an expression is not a constant
expression if it contains an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion,
*unless* it is applied to "a glvalue of integral or enumeration
type that refers to a non-volatile const object with a preceding
initialization, initialized with a constant expression".  (There
are some other cases, but they don't apply here.)  Note the
requirement for a "preceding initialization"; not only must the
variable be const, but the compiler must be able to see its
initialization.

Earlier versions of the standard were somewhat vague in this
regard, and the natural interpretation of what they literally
say would suggest that your code be legal.  This was certainly
not what was intended, however; no compiler implemented it in
this way (since it would generally require breaking separate
compilation), and C++11 clearly says that this is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not java. Use enums:

```
enum Person
{
  Person_male = 1,
  Person_female = 2
};
```

Comment: True, C++ is not Java, but that doesn't mean we have to use an `enum` here.

Comment: No, he doesn't *have* to use an enum, but is the best solution to what he is trying to do.